# java calculating number of bigrams in string

Tags: java

I have the following method which creates bigrams of input. I need to calculate the number of bigrams to calculate the probability of each occurrence.

```
public static String sortCountBigrams(ArrayList<String> bigrams) {
    String outputResult = "";
    Collections.sort(bigrams);
    String curr = bigrams.get(0);
    int counter = 1;
    for (String next : bigrams) {
        if (next.equals(curr)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            outputResult += curr + " " + Double.toString(counter) + " ";
            counter = 1;
            curr = next;
        }
    }
    return outputResult; 

}
```

this is a sample output of the bigram looks as follows:

```
af 22 ag 22 ah 7 ai 53 aj 74 ak 1 al 384 am 157
```

I need to add the calculation (below) into the method, is there a function in the java library that can do this where the number of elements in the bigram is not a constant.

```
af 22/8 ag 22/8 ah 7/8 ai 53/8 aj 74/8 ak 1/8 al 384/8 am 157/8
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that really the way you calculate probability. For ex. 22/8, 384/8. You do realize that it can never be greater than 1. Maybe you are looking for `22/(22+22+7+53+74+1+384+157)` and so on?

Comment: Your first statement is correct. Most probabilities will be much less than 1. This is what im aiming for.

Comment: You can get the divider by dividing the number of elements in your list (16) by 2

Comment: Is there a function to calculate the number of elements? This is not a constant. @Bentaye

Comment: just to clarify, is `af 22 ag 22 ah 7 ai 53 aj 74 ak 1 al 384 am 157` the input list? If not, where do you get the numbers from?

Comment: @AdityaBhardwaj My understanding is number of elements in a string reflects the index, not the number of 'words' or integers? could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Bentaye There are thousands of bigrams in the string (the two characters) and frequency doubles, i was only providing a sample.

Comment: @kp-a The number of elements do reflect the 'words' and 'integers'.

Comment: I need the number of elements to reflect the total number of doubles in the string, which is not a constant

Answer (score 2):

Fist one can collect the counts of every bigram:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = bigrams().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting());
double denominator = counts.size(); // Really not bigrams.size()?
```

As asked I have set the denominator to the number of different bigrams, not the number of all bigrams (that would give a frequency table).

```
Map<String, Double> results = new LinkedHashMap<>();
counts.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed()
        .thenComparing(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByKey()))
    .forEachOrdered(e -> results.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue() / denominator));

System.out.println(results);
```

By using a LinkedHashMap the order of insertion into the map is maintained.
As sorting order I elected most frequent first, then by bigram text.

I made the denominator immediately a double, in order to have floating point division, not integral division.

Though the stream notation comes with a harsh syntax, it is nicely compact.

Comment: Thanks so much! took me a few days to read up the java docs on hashmaps. This is a really nice solution. @Joop Eggen

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
public static String sortCountBigrams(ArrayList<String> bigrams) {
    String outputResult = "";
    Collections.sort(bigrams);
    int size = bigrams.size(); //use size to get the total no of elements
    String curr = bigrams.get(0);
    int counter = 1;
    for (String next : bigrams) {
        if (next.equals(curr)) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            outputResult += curr + " " + (Double.toString(counter))/size + " "; //divide by size here 
            counter = 1;
            curr = next;
        }
    }
    return outputResult; 
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but my question is how to find the denominator, or the number of bigrams in the string. I've given a constant of 8 in the example for simplicity.

Comment: Use `size()` to find the total elements or add them to a `hashset` so that only unique entries are there so that you can count them.

Comment: My understanding of hashsets is that it is calculated on the item index in the array. since there are multiple characters in each double, and the pairs of characters, the number of characters in the array is not what i'm looking for. I'm not familiar with a size() function, cannot find in javadocs either..

Answer (score 0):

Make a `Map` where keys are bigrams and values are their corresponding frequenciy, in a `SortedMap` (using `TreeMap` here).

Then calculate the sum of all the frequencies.

Finally, go through the map keys (bigrams) and calculate their probability (as frequency/sum)

```
public static String sortCountBigrams(List<String> inputList) {
    Map<String, Integer> bigramsAndFrequencies = new TreeMap<>();

    // Make the Map and calculate the sum of frequencies
    int sum = 0;
    int frequency;
    String bigram;
    for(int i=0; i<inputList.size(); i = i+2) {
        bigram = inputList.get(i);
        frequency = Integer.valueOf(inputList.get(i+1));
        bigramsAndFrequencies.put(bigram, frequency);
        sum += frequency;
    }

    System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    System.out.println("bigramsAndFrequencies = " + bigramsAndFrequencies);

    // Build the output String
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    for(String b : bigramsAndFrequencies.keySet()) {
        if(!first) {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
        first = false;
        sb.append(b)
          .append(" ");
          .append((double)bigramsAndFrequencies.get(b) / (double)(sum));
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Outputs

```
sum = 720
bigramsAndFrequencies = {af=22, ag=22, ah=7, ai=53, aj=74, ak=1, al=384, am=157}
af 0.030555555555555555 ag 0.030555555555555555 ah 0.009722222222222222 ai 0.07361111111111111 aj 0.10277777777777777 ak 0.001388888888888889 al 0.5333333333333333 am 0.21805555555555556
```

or

```
sb.append(b)
  .append(" ")
  .append(bigramsAndFrequencies.get(b))
  .append("/")
  .append(sum);
```

if you want this output format:

```
af 22/720 ag 22/720 ah 7/720 ai 53/720 aj 74/720 ak 1/720 al 384/720 am 157/720
```